# Exception in Apache Tomcat logs while deploying a Web Service leading to error: 404

Tags: tomcat, jax-ws, http-status-code-404

I am getting this exception in apache tomcat logs

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor:
```

As a result i m getting error 404

this is my web.xml file

```
<web-app version="2.4" mlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<description>HelloWorld</description>
<display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<description>JAX-WS endpoint - HelloWorld</description>
<display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
<servlet-name>HelloWorldPort</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HelloWorldPort</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/helloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Please someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your xml namespaces are unparseable (as indicated by the exception). Take for example you have

> mlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

Where you should have

> xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

As a result, any of the elements defined under that namespace (like `web-app` for example) will cause the runtime to choke when compiling your descriptor.